# How can I make the element stay in its place with CSS when hovering

Tags: html, css

I have an element and when I want to hover over it. It shows the border as I want, but, what it does is that it scales the text and actually moves it...

Like so:-

BEFORE TRANSITION

[image: Before the Transition]

AFTER TRANSITION

[image]

As you can see in the images the "About Us" moved left a bit after hovering and that's because of the border. How can I make it stay in its place?
This is my code

```
&--dropdown {
      list-style: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 25rem;
      height: 14rem;
      background-color: $color-additional;
      overflow: hidden;

      &-item {
        position: relative;
        width: 34rem;
        padding: 1rem 0 1rem 2rem;
        transition: all ease 0.2s;
        &:not(:first-of-type) {
          border-top: 1px solid $color-navigation-border;
        }
        &:hover {
          background-color: $color-white;
          border-left: 5px solid $color-primary;
        }
        &-link {
          color: $color-black;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Clarify by adding codes here

Comment: Did you try using the `outline` property, instead of `border`? Or the property `box-sizing` set to `border-box`. A glimpse of your code will help here. Another method will be to add a border permanently, whether the element has hovered or not, and set the border colour to the background colour, in the initial state.

Comment: @AkshitMehra There you go. Code was added

Comment: @AkshitMehra `outline` is not a good idea and `box-sizing: border-box` won't work. Your last approach, however, would work.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron3219 for rectifying! Your posted answer would work very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an `outline` for this. Instead, lower the left padding by the amount the border adds.

```css
li {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  list-style: none;
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li:hover {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test2</li>
```

This is how you have it right now. The `padding-left` is `30px` and on `:hover` the `border-left` adds `5px`. So just subtract the `border-left` width from the `padding-left` width:

```css
li {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  list-style: none;
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li:hover {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test2</li>
```

### Edit:

Since you provided some code now, just change it to this:

```
&--dropdown {
      list-style: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 25rem;
      height: 14rem;
      background-color: $color-additional;
      overflow: hidden;

      &-item {
        position: relative;
        width: 34rem;
        padding: 1rem 0 1rem 2rem;
        transition: all ease 0.2s;
        &:not(:first-of-type) {
          border-top: 1px solid $color-navigation-border;
        }
        &:hover {
          background-color: $color-white;
          border-left: 5px solid $color-primary;
          padding-left: calc(2rem - 5px); //<-- I added this line of code
        }
        &-link {
          color: $color-black;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: No problem ;). Also take a note of Akshit Mehra's answer as it will also work. Just decide what you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note:** this is one of the many solutions to this problem.

You can define a border for both the states, initial, as well as `:hover`. In the initial state, the border's colour should be set the same as the background colour of the item, which can be changed in the `hover` state.

```
&-item {
    border-left: 5px solid <your_bg_colour>;
    &:hover {
      border-left-color: <hover_state_colour>;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just used the first solution of  @Aaron3219 Thanks anyway